# Wolfram Alpha Ignoring Log Rules?

Tags: logarithms, wolfram-alpha

Why does Wolfram Alpha say that $\underbrace{\ln(y(y^{2}-4))}_\text{EQ1} \neq \underbrace{\ln(y) + \ln(y-2) + \ln(y+2)}_\text{EQ2}$ ([seen here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%20ln(y)%20%2B%20ln(y-2)%20%2B%20ln(y%2B2)%20equal%20to%20ln(y(y%5E2-4))))?

The *Produce Rule of Logarithms* states that:
$$\log_b{(M*N)}=\log_b{M} + \log_b{N}$$

Therefore, 
$$ \begin{align}  \ln(y) + \ln(y-2) + \ln(y+2)& = \\ \ln(y) + \ln((y-2)(y+2)) & = \\ \ln(y) + \ln(y^2-4) & = \ln(y(y^2 - 4)) = \mathbf{EQ1} \ \checkmark \end{align} $$

However, Wolfram Alpha is saying that **EQ1** *"is **not** always equal to"* **EQ2**. The graph Wolfram provides feels problematic, because it is showing two dramatically different curves when in reality both sizes are the same curve. **What am I missing here?**

Comment: Likely it’s assuming that $y$ is complex.

Comment: What do you expected e.g. for $y=-3?$

Comment: For $y = -1$, the LHS is well defined, but for the RHS, none of them are valid when considering $y \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Or when $y=-1$ ? (oops - xbh just said that !)

Comment: In Mathematica, "Simplify[Log[y (y^2 - 4)] - Log[y] - Log[y - 2] - Log[y + 2], 
 Assumptions -> y > 2]" works, but I don't know how to do this in Alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example: $\ln(y(y^2-4))$ is defined for $y=-1$, but $\ln(y) + \ln(y-2) + \ln(y+2)$ is not defined for $y=-1$.

The rule $\log_b{(M*N)}=\log_b{M} + \log_b{N}$ is only valid if both $M$ and $N$ are positive !

Comment: Quick question, if I was to encapsulate each interior with absolute values (i.e. $\ln|y(y^{2}-4)| \stackrel{?}{=} \ln|y| + \ln|y-2| + \ln|y+2|$), why is it still **not** always equal to each other?